# Is $X$ a Borel subset of $\beta X$?

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets, borel-measures

Consider a Tychonoff space $X$ and $\beta X$ its Stone-$\check{\rm C}$ech compactification. I'm currently studying the existence of certain types of regular Borel measures on $X$. Since it's much simpler to obtain regular Borel meaures for a compact, I'd like to obtain them for $\beta X$, and then consider the restriction to $X$. To do so, I'd like to know whether $X$ is a Borel subset of $\beta X$.

Comment: $X$ is never closed in $\beta X$ (unless $X=\beta X$), it's open iff $X$ is locally compact and it's a $G_\delta$ iff it so-called "Cech complete" (aka topologically complete). It's an $F_\sigma$ iff it's $\sigma$-compact. Higher classes characterisations I'm not really aware of, and probably get harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It need not be. I’ve not read the paper, but K.C. Goswami has a paper [*Density topology on R is not a Borel subset of its Stone-Čech compactification*](https://insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20005a69_45.pdf) [PDF]. It uses results from Ichiro Amemiya, Susumu Okada, Yoshiaki Okazaki, [*Pre-Radon measures on topological spaces*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kmj/1138035444) [PDF], which I have also not read.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references

Comment: @AndréPorto: You’re very welcome.